# How to sort files by creation date using java 1.6

Tags: java, file, directory, java-6

I have a folder with files in there, I have to sort those files by their creation date.

So I want to sort from the oldest to the newest file by creation date.

I saw many answers working with java nio but since I am working with java 1.6 I can not use java nio.

I need help, is there any solution?

Comment: Thank you for the advice but I have some constraints and using java 1.6 is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a third party library try [JavaXT Core](http://www.javaxt.com/javaxt-core/). Should work with Java 1.5 and up.

```
    javaxt.io.File file = new javaxt.io.File("C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\myFile.txt");
    System.out.println("Created: " + file.getCreationTime());
    System.out.println("Accessed: " + file.getLastAccessTime());
    System.out.println("Modified: " + file.getLastModifiedTime());
```

Comment: Here is a proper answer I was looking for ! Thank you a lot !